# How to query DNS with "DNSSEC OK" (DO) bit in Python Asynchronously?

Tags: python, dns

How to query DNS with "DNSSEC OK" (DO) bit in Python Asynchronously?
I have researched on pythondns , aiodns but they do not offer a function to set the "DNSSEC OK" (DO) bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply open a UDP socket and then craft the complete DNS packet by hand. This would be the obvious approach. 
If you want to use a library I would have a look at dpkt. Note that it is badly documented, but very powerful. It also allows you to set the DNS Opcode's directly.

For the asynchronous part you should have a look at threading.

Comment: However, that would be harder to manage compare to using external APIs.

Comment: @NicholsChew I would then have a look at dpkt